# Want to add a border to the last section, but not the last section of the parent

Tags: css

I want to apply CSS to the below-given elements... I want to add a border to the last section, but not the last section of the parent. I have mentioned by "" where i want to apply CSS. Thank you for your time.

```
<div>
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> <!-- this -->
    <h4></h4>
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> <!-- this -->   
    <h4></h4>
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> <!-- this -->   
    <h4></h4>
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div> <!-- this -->   
    <h4></h4>
    <div class="section"></div> 
    <div class="section"></div>  <!-- this -->  
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify the criteria?

Comment: @MaikHasler I have edited the question and tried to explain more.